# Connecting to to wifi network in iOS 11 "Unable to join the network"

Tags: ios, swift, networking

I'm trying to connect to wifi network inside app. using the code below:

```
let hotspotConfig = NEHotspotConfiguration(ssid: "testNetwork")
hotspotConfig.joinOnce = true
NEHotspotConfigurationManager.shared.apply(hotspotConfig) { (configurationError) in
    if configurationError != nil {
      print("error")
      print(configurationError!.localizedDescription)
    } else {
      print("success")
    }        
}
```

But when I'm unable to join the network I get an **Alert** saying :
"Unable to join the network testNetwork"

My question is there any way to **not** display the alert if i'm unable to connect?

Comment: Do you have found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you can't intercept and hide that message since it is handled by the OS (same as for the join network popup).